# How to replace properties file value using key in Unix shell scripting?

Tags: shell

### I have one properties file mongo.properties present in Config folder like this.

mongo.host=192.165.2.20

I want to replace value of host through key.Here what i tried mentioned.

### here is my script file

> mongo_host=192.2.2.2
>   sed -i "s#mongo.host#$mongo_host#g" "/Config/mongo.properties"

But it is replacing key itself.

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: @Shammel i got the solution. i was doing mistake that in property file i have to keep placeholder instead of value.Like this. mongo.host=192.165.2.20 should be  mongo.host=mongo.host